# VISIO 2016 - Shape Data Cannot be shown

Tags: shapes, visio

I created a "Document" shape under "Basic Flowchart". Then, I followed the link below and try to add data and I expect the data will be shown within the Shape. However, there is nothing after I typed the data into the "Shape Data Panel"

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-data-to-shapes-09272394-5243-4e1b-bcfa-425a8b4d1ce2

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the answer is using "Insert > Field" function to add the field one by one

Comment: Shapes can have dozens of fields. It wouldn't make sense to display them automatically in the shape. Separating the content from the display makes more sense. Doesn't it?